# how to call in main I'm getting error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I want to convert NSString to NSdate and back using category. I'm having trouble in calling.

```
+ (NSDate*)stringDateFromString:(NSString*)string
{
  NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
  NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  // voila!
  dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
  return dateFromString;
}

+ (NSString*)StringFromDate :(NSDate*)date
{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
  NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
  NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
  return stringDate;
}
```

Comment: did you mix up definition and declaration of the methods? because either the `;` must not be there after the function header or the function header is missing for the actual implementation - anyway: what error?

Comment: you are using `+` methods then you have to call these with class name (not object of class). If you want to call with object you need to change `+` with `-`. or just accept my edit.

Comment: this category must be class of `NSString` or `NSDate`.

Comment: Please show the full category extenstion code.

Comment: There have been edits made to the code within your question. Please ensure that the question does reflect the code as it is currently in your project. Although the ';' semikolons may have been wrongly placed in the original question, exactly this could have been your problem.

Comment: Are you aware that your methods are class methods? 
There is nothing wrong with having class methods, especially in this case. But you must call them accordingly.

Comment: What exactly is the trouble thate you are having? Does it compile? Does it return null or nonsense?

Comment: I m using category for the above code. I m able to call +(NSString*)StringFromDate :(NSDate*)date;

Comment: I got the output as "23-06-2015"

Comment: But I'm not getting output of other method i.e + (NSDate*)dateFromString:(NSString*)string
{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
  NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  // voila!
  dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
  return dateFromString;
} is not getting called and even no errors

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code you have provided you will need to create a category as follows:-

NSString+Utils.h

```
@interface NSString (Utils)
+ (NSDate*)dateFromString:(NSString*)string;
+ (NSString*)stringFromDate:(NSDate*)date;
@end
```

NSString+Utils.m

```
@implementation NSString (Utils)

+ (NSDate*)dateFromString:(NSString*)string
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
    return dateFromString;
}

+ (NSString*)stringFromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
    return stringDate;
}

@end
```

And to call either method:-

```
NSDate *date = [NSString dateFromString:@"22-06-2015"];
NSString *string = [NSString stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"----------------");
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
NSLog(@"String: %@", string);
NSLog(@"----------------");
```

Please be aware that [allocating NSDateFormatter is expensive](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW10) so you might not want to be doing too many calls to these methods (in a table view for example).

**Output from XCTestCase**

```
Test Case '-[stackTests testExample]' started.
2015-06-23 07:12:59.601 xctest[3103:49715] 22-06-2015
2015-06-23 07:12:59.601 xctest[3103:49715] ----------------
2015-06-23 07:12:59.602 xctest[3103:49715] Date: 2015-06-21 23:00:00 +0000
2015-06-23 07:12:59.602 xctest[3103:49715] String: 22-06-2015
2015-06-23 07:12:59.602 xctest[3103:49715] ----------------
Test Case '-[stackTests testExample]' passed (0.002 seconds).
```

Comment: Only NSString *string = [NSString stringFromDate:date]; getting called.   Why NSDate *date = [NSString dateFromString:@"22-06-2015"]; not getting called?..

Comment: Hi Steve! thanks for the answer. I dint get output for first method.. while second method got called. I'm not getting any errors too. So unable to find out why the output is not coming

Comment: Using the code I originally provided would have actually resulted in compiler errors & warnings. I have updated the code so that it will work.  have tested it in an XCTestCase and the output is shown in the updated answer.